# What are the odds that the Dems can take the Senate in 2018?

Tags: probability

[In 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate_elections,_2018), 25 Democratic or Democratic-caucusing senators are up for re-election, along with 9 GOP senators.

To win control of the Senate, the Democrats have to gain at least 5 seats.  That is, all the incumbent Dems hold their seats, while at least 5 Republicans lose, or exactly 24 Dems win and at least 6 Republicans lose, and so on.

For the sake of argument, assume that the probability of a senator winning re-election is [0.80](https://www.opensecrets.org/overview/reelect.php).

All the ways I can figure out to solve this are absurdly complicated.  Is there some reasonably simple way to figure this out?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with U.S. laws but shouldn't it be 33 seats instead of 34?

Comment: @Dleep - There are 50 states, each with 2 senators, so 100 total.  "One third" are up for reelection every two years, but since 100 is not divisible by 3, that means one election every six years, the "class" (as its called) is 34.

Comment: I think you mean the probability, not the odds.  A probability of $0.80$ means odds $4$ to $1$ in favour.

Comment: @Malvolio and according to Wikipedia, they switched over 34 senators last year so in 2018 and 2020 it should be 33.

Comment: @Dleep -- you're right: the 34th is a special election to replace Alabama Senator Jeff Sessions, who left the Senate to become Attorney General (in the US system, the equivalent of both the Minister of Justice and the Chief Prosecutor).  Obviously, if the Democrats had a really good shot at taking the seat, he would never have left it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that exactly $k$ of the currently-Democratic seats seats stay Democratic and exactly $m$ of the currently-Republican seats go Democratic is
${25 \choose k} {9 \choose m} (4/5)^{k + 9-m} (1/5)^{25-k+m}$, $0 \le k \le 25$, $0 \le m \le 9$.  You want to sum those terms such that $k + m \ge 30$.  Note that for such a term, $9 \ge m \ge 30 - k$ so $k \ge 30 - 9 = 21$.

$$ \sum_{k=21}^{25} \sum_{m = 30-k}^9  {25 \choose k} {9 \choose m} (4/5)^{k + 9-m} (1/5)^{25-k+m} \approx 0.0001712788723 $$

Comment: Huh.  I used that logic too and got 0.00014436.  I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's a pretty low probability. In order to avoid sinking into despair I'm going to have to hope that the model is inaccurate.

Comment: The model _is_ inaccurate!  In the average year, the probability is around 0.80 and the events are independent... but these are not average years!

Comment: Note also that the $0.8$, even if accurate, is only for a senator seeking re-election.  It may not be the same as the probability of a party retaining the seat when a senator retires.

Comment: @RobertIsrael -- I can't imagine many senators are will be retiring this time around, and certainly very few whose parties don't have a firm grip on their respective states.  Orrin Hatch might not run again, and there are rumors that DiFi is thinking of hanging it up, but they both hail from one-party states.